# Conversion from JSON to POJO having sub JSON in java

Tags: java, json

I am trying to convert from JSON event to a POJO and by keeping sub JSON as it is in the POJO but getting null.

My POJO is this

```
private String accountId;
private String clientId;
private String datacenter;
private EventType eventType;
private String eventId;
private Long eventRaisedTimeMillis;
private EntityType entityType;
private String entityId;
private String alertName;
private String feature;
private String alertMetadata;
private String alertCondition;
private Map<String, String> attributeValues;
```

And my event is producing is this:

```
{
  "clientId": "abc",
  "accountId": "account1",
  "eventType": "STRESS",
  "datacenter": "v",
  "eventRaisedTimeMillis": 1627302648497,
  "entityId": "xyz",
  "entityType": "QUEUE",
  "eventId": "UUID",
  "alertName": "QueueAWT",
  "feature": "Fallback",
  "alertMetaData": {
    "value": {
      "queues": [
        "Q1",
        "Q2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "alertCondition": "JSON",
  "attribute_values": {
    "attr1": "value1",
    "attr2": "value2"
  }
}
```

But I am getting this as output on consuming from kafka:

> (accountId=accounnt1, clientId=abc,
> eventType=STRESS, eventId=UUID,
> eventRaisedTimeMillis=1627302648497, entityType=QUEUE,
> entityId=xyz, alertName=QueueAWT,
> feature=Fallback, alertMetadata=null, alertCondition=JSON,
> attributeValues=null)

One way is to create a class for alertMetadata but do not want to do that but rather store it as sub JSON inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what JSON library you are using, but your POJO has no annotations. So, your JSON has `alertMetaData`, and the POJO has `alertMetadata`... These should match. Also note `attribute_values` is null for `attributeValues` as well. With Jackson, you can use `@JsonProperty` to fix this

For example

```
@JsonProperty(value = "alertMetaData")
private String alertMetadata;

@JsonProperty(value = "attribute_values")
private Map<String, String> attributeValues;
```

You're also producing an Object for the metadata, but the POJO has just a string. If you don't want to create a nested class, then use a `Map<String, Object>`, similarly to how you did for the `attributeValues`

Comment: After using above, I am getting this error:
`Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token
(through reference chain: ["alertMetaData"])`

Comment: Like I said, your types don't match. Your metadata field needs to be a Map or object class

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting the json from the web, I recommend you to use @RequestBody to get the JSON data and then using Mapstruct to map the attributes from JSON to your POJO

```
toPOJO(@RequestBody JsonDTO jsonDTO)
```

then you can use mapstruct like this, to map everything:

```
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;
import org.mapstruct.Mapping;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface PojoMapper {

    @Mapping(source = "attribute_values", target = "attributeValues")
    Pojo toEntity(JsonDTO jsonDTO);

}
```

keep in mind you can use as many @Mapping annotations as you need if your Json attributes have different names from your pojo attributes...

a mapperImpl file will be automatically created when you run maven clean install, mapping everything that came from the json to your pojo.